# What does "Is there any place to sell Korean food and beverage?" mean?

Tags: grammar

Can we say:

> "Is there any place to sell Korean food and beverage?"
>   "Is there any place to sell hamburgers around here?"

instead of:

> "Is there any place **which/that** sell**s** Korean food and beverage?"
>   "Is there any place **which/that** sell**s** hamburgers around here?"

like in this link: http://www.grammaring.com/the-to-infinitive-to-replace-a-relative-clause

Comment: It depends.  Are you *selling* X or *buying* X?

Answer (score 6):

The basic meaning of "Is there any place to sell hamburgers around here" would be "Is there a place where *I can sell my hamburgers*".  That is such a strange thing to ask that I would probably be quite confused.

You can ask:

> Is there any place **to buy** hamburgers?

which has roughly the same meaning as:

> Is there any place **that sells** hamburgers?

Answer (score 3):

"Is there anyplace to sell (something)" means that **you** are the one who wants to do the selling.

> Is there anyplace to sell my used car around here?

Since you want to buy, you ask if there is anyplace **that** sells.

The link you give does not apply to your example, as it does not meet the three mentioned criteria.

Comment: I agree and upvoted, but don't much think this is an ask. It's really a question.